# Difference in definition of Krull dimension

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

The definition of Krull dimension of a module over a ring $R$ in the sense of deviation of the poset of submodules ordered by inclusion may not coincide with the definition for non-Noetherian rings $R$ (though this is the case when $R$ is Noetherian). I want an example to show this difference.

Also, if all the prime ideals of a commutative (not necessarily Noetherian) ring  $R$ are maximal could one deduce that the module $R_R$ has Krull dimension (in the sense of deviation of poset of its ideals)?

Thanks, in advance, for any cooperation!

Comment: What's "deviation"?

Comment: @user26857 Let $R$ be a ring and let $M$ be a right $R$-module. The Krull dimension $k(M)$ of $M$ is defined as follows: $k(M)=-1$ if and only if $M=0$. If $\alpha \ge 0$ is an ordinal such that all modules with Krull dimension less than $\alpha $ are known, then $k(M) \le \alpha$ if for every chain $... \subseteq M_2 \subseteq M_1 \subseteq M_0=M$ of submodules of $M$ there is a positive integer $n$  with $k(M_i/M_{i+1})<\alpha$ for all $i\ge n$. Hence $M$ is artinian if and only if $k(M)=0$, so this dimension measures how far a module is deviated from being artinian